# For Loop in Javascript outputs value only from last iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, settimeout

I have this Javascript code, which works as expected:

```
<div class="test"></div>

<script>
setTimeout(function(){$(".test").append("test1")},1000);
setTimeout(function(){$(".test").append("test2")},2000);
</script>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It shows "test1" first and then "test2" a second later, as such:  "test1test2", which is what I want.

When I try to do this in a FOR loop, like this:

```
var timeInterval = 1000;
for (var i = 0, l = 2; i < l; i++ ) {
    setTimeout(function(){$(".test").append("test" + i)},timeInterval);
    timeInterval += 1000;
}
```

Then I get "test2" first and then "test2" a second later, as such:  "test2test2", which is not what I want.

In fact, if l = 3, then I get "test3test3test3" instead of "test1test2test3".  Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: I think because the timeout is longer then the speed it is going through i, so by the time it evaluates i it is already at 3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The var `i` is incremented to 2 when the `setTimeout` is executing the function and so it just prints the `i` value as 2 resulting in `test2test2`.

You should use a closure to use the instance of `i` which will print `test1test`.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/mBBJn/1/

```
var timeInterval = 1000;
for (var i = 0, l = 2; i < l; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(".test").append("test" + (i+1))
        }, timeInterval);
        timeInterval += 1000;
    })(i);
}
```

**Edit:** used function args.

Answer (score 3):

The for loop doesn't create a new scope, you can use another function to do it:

```
var timeInterval = 1000;
for (var i = 0, l = 2; i < l; i++) {
    setTimeout((function(i) {
        return function() {
            $(".test").append("test" + i);
        }
    })(i), timeInterval);
    timeInterval += 1000;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The variable `i` will always refer to the current value of `i` (not the value of `i` when called) in this situation.

That's how scope works in JavaScript.

See the answer by @Esailija for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you aren't capturing the value of `i` from the for-loop. You can tweak your code to this to make it work:

```
var timeInterval = 1000;
for (var i = 0, l = 2; i < l; i++ ) {
    (function(i2, timeInterval2) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(".test").append("test" + i2);
        }, timeInterval2);
    })(i, timeInterval);
    timeInterval += 1000;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Cory for your suggestion.  You need to remove one of the close brackets from:  timeInterval)); to timeInterval); and it works.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious way to keep `i` in scope is solved in other answers, but since you're using jQuery you have other options.

1. Use `$.each` instead of `for` loop, that way you have access to `i` variable anywhere in that scope.
2. Use `delay` instead of `setTimeout`. For this to work you need to trigger a queue first: `$(".test").show(0).delay(timeInterval).append("test" + i)`