# why is the array[i] value only returning the last value for each markerLabel?

Tags: javascript

I cannot seem to get the markerLabel to access location i,1 in the locations array.  I have moved it around and no matter where I place it it returns 45 for all 6 markerLabels which is locations[5][1]. I should have a markerLabel 31, markerLabel 33, markerLabel 34, etc as it runs through the loop. The addresses found in locations[i][0] all display accurately. I have commented out the secondary places I think it should go and left it where I believe it should be.  Any insights of what I am missing would be appreciated.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
  <title>Google Maps Multiple Markers</title> 
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
          type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head> 
<body>
    <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>



<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var locations = [
        ['3026 East College Ave, Ruskin, Fl, USA','31'], 
        ['517 19th Street Northwest, Ruskin, Fl, USA','33'],
        ['101 College Avenue East, Ruskin, Fl, USA','34'],
        ['3350 Laurel Ridge Ave, Ruskin, Fl, USA','37'],
        ['409 Laguna Mill Dr, Ruskin, Fl, USA','40'],
        ['2302 Lloyd Dr, Ruskin, Fl, USA','45']
        ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 12,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(27.714616,-82.393298),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    });


    var marker, i, markerLabel;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
     var markerLabel = locations[i][1];
        $.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+locations[i][0]+'&sensor=false', null, function (data) {
            var p = data.results[0].geometry.location
          //var markerLabel = locations[i][1];
           marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(p.lat, p.lng),
                map: map,
                label: {
                    //text: locations[i][1];
                    text: markerLabel,
                    color: "#fff",
                    fontSize: "16px",
                    fontWeight: "bold"
                } //label
            }); // Marker

        }); //$.getJSON
    } //for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++)

}); //$(document).ready(function ()

</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [For Loop in Javascript outputs value only from last iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13077828/for-loop-in-javascript-outputs-value-only-from-last-iteration)

Comment: Though not exactly the same, the linked answer does solve a similar problem.  It does so via closure, which is a worthwhile concept to know if you're going to spend much time in javascript.

Comment: Except that it outputs element 1 correctly all 6 times however element 2 displays the 6th output all 6 times.  Your link shows it only outputs the last element.  That is not the case here.  The first element is correct.  It is only the second element that is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calls to `$.getJSON` are asynchronous.  Which means that, your loop runs all of its iterations *immediately* and fires off those async calls.  It changes the values of `i` and `markerValue` 6 times in rapid succession *before* any of the ajax calls can complete, and then when those functions do finally complete and trigger their callback, they end up accessing a value that's been altered in their scope and you end up with the same result.

You need to isolate the scope of the individual ajax requests so that they don't all refer to the same variables.  This should be enough to do that:

```
function make_request(i) {
    $.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+locations[i][0]+'&sensor=false', null, function (data) {
       var p = data.results[0].geometry.location
       marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(p.lat, p.lng),
            map: map,
            label: {
                text: locations[i][1],
                color: "#fff",
                fontSize: "16px",
                fontWeight: "bold"
            } //label
        }); // Marker

    }); //$.getJSON
}

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    make_request(i);
} //for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++)
```

Comment: Thank you!  I did not realize it would fire JSON in rapid succession.  Thank you for explaining it so clearly.

Comment: No worries.  Any time you're using AJAX, try to think of it as "these will all happen _later_, after whatever I'm doing _right now_ finishes".  You have to compartmentalize your thinking a little bit.  It's a quirky thing at first, but it gets easier with time.

Comment: `for (let i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {` should also solve the problem.